# How to create an installer for node js command line app

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation, command-line

I have been searching for how to create an installer for node js command line applications.
I need to be able to globally install the app so it can be accessed from in the command line.

Comment: you could create a bat file in windows or bash in mac .

Comment: Yes, I have tried creating a batch file and converting it a .exe file, but all that did was run 'node index.js' and I need a file that will install it and doesnt require node for people who dont have it already installed

Comment: so the best solution is electronJs

Answer (score 0):

As one of the commenters has already said, Electron JS is probably the best way to do this: https://www.electronjs.org/